# Как с помощью preg_mactch запретить вводить после числа минус?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Суть такова, мне нужно, чтобы когда вводился "-1", preg_match его пропускал, а когда "1-" он не пропускал.

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]*\.*\-?[0-9]*$/';
```

Comment: `echo substr($n, -1) === '-';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем регулярки если можно использовать **[strripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php)**. Он возвращает последнее вхождение символа. Нужно проверить, что если оно не 0, то "досвидос"